# Powershell versions compatibility in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

Hello guys i'm running powershell in wy asp.net mvc5 application this script works fine on local machine but when hosting the app in a remote server that uses a powershell version earlier than the one in local machine it gives me the following error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

I need to know how can i deal with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Management.Automation` V3 is not resolved on your remote server.

This could be because you target .Net Framework 4.0 or more in your application and want to deploy it on a computer with Powershell 2.0

You have 2 options:

> Downgrade your solution to .Net Framework 3.5

or

> Upgrade the Powershell version on your target machine